# I am using Views Calc module but giving error

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am using Views Calc Module in drupal 7.

I want to calculate and show sum of price of products.

The Views Calc module giving error-

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns
 (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

Please help me What I do for resolve this problem and tell me if any alternate method.

Answer (score 0):

> *Mixing of GROUP columns
>    (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause.*

Error message is very clear. You have to use `group by` clause to use aggregate functions on any column. That aggregation instruction should be passed through `group by` clause.

You need to frame your query something like this:

```
select 
  product_id,
  min(price) min_price,
  max(pric) max_price,
  count(product_id) product_count
from 
  products_table
group by
  product_id
```